# Add column of order SKU's to admin orders page

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm adding a custom column to admin orders table (based on [this article](http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-orders-grid/)).

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    // here I'm fetching data
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
        ->join(
                'sales/order_item',
                '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
                array(
                    'skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",")'),
                    'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")')
                    )
            );
    $collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Skus'),
    'width'     => '100px',
    'index'     => 'skus',
    'type'        => 'text',

    ));
    $this->addColumn('names', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Name'),
    'width'     => '100px',
    'index'     => 'names',
    'type'        => 'text',
    ));

    // e.t.c.
}
```

Which works fine, I can now see the SKU's and product names of orders in this table.

Except one big flaw, each SKU and Product Name is printed twice . I assume that it's because configurable products are sold.

Is there any way to prevents this duplication and force it to select only simple products?

Comment: Be very careful joining live production tables into the admin sales order grid - any goofy thing an admin may search by can cause locking on the production sales table, causing an order to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
public function callback_skus($value, $row, $column, $isExport) {
    $_items = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($value)->getAllItems();

    $skus_arr = array();
    foreach ($_items as $item) {
        array_push($skus_arr, $item->getSku());
    }
    $skus_arr = array_unique($skus_arr);

    return implode("<br/>",$skus_arr);
}


protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
         'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU\'s'),
         'index' => 'increment_id',
         'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_skus')
    ));
}
```

Not sure if it's the fastest way, but at least it works and doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try with an additional condition on the join.
Something like  `AND ISNULL(sales/order_item.parent_item_id)`.

And I'm curious if your pagination still works after adding the `group by` statement.

Comment: oh, pagination really doesn't work, thank you for heads-up I even haven't noticed this. If I don't add `group by` it displays all skus in one field and I have only one row, for some weird reason. I've changed the title of thread.